# Two book series about humans grown from DNA sent from earth who are seeking their origins

Tags: story-identification, books

There were two books in the set. Humans are living in another galaxy within an alien culture. They discover that they were grown by this other species based on DNA code beamed from Earth ages before. A group of humans are eventually given permission to make their way back to earth. During their travels they piece together the history of humanity and what befell them.

I have searched every author I can think of but can't find them. It feels so much like a Baxter novel but I don't see anything by him.

Answer (score 7):

I believe you may be thinking of a set of two books by David Moffitt. *The Genesis Quest* and *Second Genesis*.

In the first book the alien species 'nar' have recreated humanity from radio transmissions broadcast centuries before... The second book deals with a group of humans who head towards the source of the radio signal to find out what happened to humanity.

One of the coolest parts of this story is that they use trees - very large trees - tethered to powerful engines to travel from star to star.

Comment: But I think you mean **Donald** Moffitt.

Comment: Thank you! that is who and what i was looking for. Moffitt....missed his name in all the possible lists i looked through.